# Increment a number in the name of textbox

Tags: c#

```
public void test()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);
        list.Add(3);
        for (int i = 1; i <= list.Count; i++)
        {

            textBx.Text = list[i].ToString();
            // I want it to be textBx1.Text = list[1].ToString();
                               textBx2.Text = list[2].ToString();
                               textBx3.Text = list[3].Tostring();
                               etc.
              // I can't create textbox dynamically as I need the text box to be placed in specific places in the form . How do I do it the best way? 


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for Controls.Find(). You could dynamically build your string and search for the TextBox with that name:

```
 var textBox = this.Controls.Find("textBx" + i, true) as TextBox;
 textBox.Text = list[i].ToString();
```

This is a bit ugly as it's predicated on your naming convention for the TextBoxes. Perhaps a better solution would be to cache a list of the TextBoxes before your loop:

```
var textBoxes = new[] { textBx1, textBx2, textBx3 };
```

Then you can simply index into the array:

```
textBoxes[i].Text = list[i].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Matt. Here's a complete solution that works:

```
        string TextBoxPrefix = "textBx";
        foreach (Control CurrentControl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (CurrentControl is TextBox)
            {
                if (CurrentControl.Name.StartsWith(TextBoxPrefix)) {

                    int TextBoxNumber = System.Convert.ToInt16(CurrentControl.Name.Substring(TextBoxPrefix.Length));

                    if (TextBoxNumber <= (list.Count - 1))
                    {
                        CurrentControl.Text = list[TextBoxNumber].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You might need to make this a recursive function, because CurrentControl could have child controls, for example if CurrentControl was a table and the text boxes were each in separate rows/cells in that table, I think your function wouln't find the text boxes.